# Connection Problem with QBFC15 64-bit version

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, quickbooks

Here is what I have:
Problem:  Trying to connect two different 64-bit applications:

1. Microsoft Access 64-bit
2. QuickBooks Entrprise 21.0 (I'm not sure if it is actually 32-bit or 64-bit)

Using:

- Visual Studio 2022 64-bit edition
- VB.NET
- 64-bit version of QBFC15 library for QuickBooks

My thought is that when you use a 64-bit API, it would connect to a 64-bit application.  I am most likely incorrect.

When I connect to MS Access in the debug 64-bit mode, it connects fine.  The Intuit developer Network says you need to publish applications in the 32-bit mode.  I have always used the 32-bit mode for publishing QuickBooks applications because they were 32-bit programs and, well, frankly, 64-bit applications hadn't come out yet (no old person jokes here).  Anyway, I was really excited to see that the 64-bit version of a QBFC library came out (QBFC15) and they offer both 32-bit and 64-bit.  So I downloaded the 64-bit version (which they recommend on their site https:\\developer.intuit.com>

So I'm thinking, hey, it's a 64-bit SDK!  Yeah!  So now I have this project that tells me I need to connect a 64-bit Access application to QuickBooks.  When I debug, my new application connects just fine to MS Access in the 64-bit mode!  Yeah!  But the 64-bit Intuit SDK needs to be published in the 32-bit mode!!!!  I'm confused.  I know that they have put the cart before the horse and I know that they must still be running QuickBooks Enterprise in the 32-bit mode but come on.  Putting out the SDK before the commercial product comes out to use it one?  (I'm done whining now...got to get it out somehow!).

So how am I to connect my application to both "64-bit" programs when one errors in the 32-bit mode and the other errors in the 64-bit mode?

The programming isn't the issue, but this scenario seems really problematic.  Do I tell the customer they need to downgrade their Microsoft Office to the 32-bit mode version?  That would be an easy answer I guess, but it sure makes me look bad.  Any other suggestions out there that could help me in this would be much appreciated.

Comment: *"The programming isn't the issue"*, SO only accepts [programming related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You may post your issue in [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: When you say connecting to 64bit MS Access .  What type of connection are we talking about?  COM Interopt or Data access?

Comment: It is data access of the 64-bit version of QBES desktop with the new SDK 15.0 (64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

If you running desktop edition of QuickBooks, then if you are running a x32 bit version of QuickBooks?

Then that means automation and working with the desktop edition means your software ALL MUST remain x32.

Only in 2022, have they rather recent upgraded and offer a x64 bit verison.

So, you have to check which desktop version of QuickBooks you are running. (most up to rather recent have been x32 bits - for a VERY long time).

So, what determines what QBFC library, what version of Access, and quite much vb.net?

You must continue to force your vb.net projects to run as x86, and NOT use "any" CPU and not use x64.

So, what will determine what all of your code is to run as?
It will be the desktop edition of QB that determines this.

It is of ZERO use to adopt office x64, access x64, or run your vb.net software, and the QBFC sdk and library as x64 bits if QuickBooks remains as x32.

(you using the wrong bit size and architecture here).

so, you have to be 100%, and in fact 200% sure
now, if QBFC is hitting the server database for QuickBooks, then that can be x64 bits but if you using the QB sdk and QBFC? Then that all must remain x32 bits until such time you upgrade the desktop edition of QuickBooks.

So, you have to REALLY but REALLY find out if in fact if you are running x32 QuickBooks for desktop, or x64 for desktop.

The version of QuickBooks and what version you you THEN much choose of QBFC library, vb.net, Access/office then again will have to match the bit size of QuickBooks desktop.

So from everything else from down to Access to vb.net to QBFC then all again much match the version of QuickBooks for desktop you have installed.

Now, if vb.net, Access you use is NOT to interface via the QBFC .dll and SDK? Then you don't care. But, inter process communication based on so called "windows COM objects"? And say upgrading from office x32, and the associated software systems you have? You can't just out of the blue decide to jump to office x64 without say your company and IT department not knowing the difference between x32 bit software, and that of x64 bit software.

Hint:  8 bit Apple II computer has a different architecture then a 16 bit IBM PC. And going from 16 bits to x32 bits? Again, a huge and large jump.

And from x32 bit software to x64 bit software? again a huge jump.

So, while windows can happy run x32 bit software, and it been a x64 bit OS by default for 10+ years?

Well, software packages running as x32 bits, and them interfacing to x64 bit software is a whole different matter. Such software has to remain the same bit size - and you can't have different bit size process on windows such as x32 bit COM objects (ole, COM, ActiveX = same technology stack).

So keep this basic knowledge and hallmark and pillar in our industry - different bit size software systems can't talk to each other via inter-op, or so called COM object automation.

Comment: So I have upgraded to the 64-bit version of QuickBooks Desktop.  I am now running the following:

QBES 22.0 (64-bit)
Microsoft Office 64-bit
Visual Studio: 64-bit
QBFC 15.0 (64-bit)

And I am now getting the error:  80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG).
Error Source: mscorlib
Error Number 429

in the line of code: sessionManager = new QBSessionManager

Comment: And you forced your .net project to x64 bits? Don't use ANY CPU, and don't use x86, but ensure that the project settings are x64 bits. So, hard to debug the error - but it does suggest that this is a bit-size miss-match. Maybe you not enabled external applications from QuickBooks. but, at least it looks like you have all parts as x64 bits now. As noted, don't risk using ANY CPU in VS - make sure you force your project as x64 bits.

Comment: Has anybody been able to connect the 64-bit SDK to the newest QBES 22 (64-bit) desktop version in Visual Studio?  If so, then I know it must be some setting that I am using.  If not, then perhaps it simply isn't doable?